# How to cycle through embed videos on click of a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sort of new to programming in general. Just as the title says how do I switch between more than 2 embed videos on click of a button?

So far I've got this

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected static int videoMode = 1;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Change_Video(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoMode == 1)
            {
                videoMode = 2;
                vid1.Attributes["src"] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hQu03xqOTsA";
            }
            else
            {
                videoMode = 1;
                vid1.Attributes["src"] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9cqsIedJew4";
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an asp HiddenField and increment the value until you reach your max and then reset it back to the first.

Or assign another attribute to your video on page load, e.g.

```
vid1.Attributes["data-video-index"] = 0;
```

Then increment it per video.

Perhaps use a switch for your videos:

```
int videoIndex = Convert.ToInt32(vid1.Attributes["data-video-index"]);
switch (videoIndex)
{ 
    case 0:
        vid1.Attributes["src"] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hQu03xqOTsA";
        vid1.Attributes["data-video-index"] = "1";
        break;
    case 1:
        vid1.Attributes["src"] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hQu03xqOTsB";
        vid1.Attributes["data-video-index"] = "2";
        break;
    case 2:
        vid1.Attributes["src"] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hQu03xqOTsC";
        vid1.Attributes["data-video-index"] = "0";
        break;
}
```